# Javascript variable scope issues?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have used **mongoose** and **Node.js** and I am facing this issue:

```
var dbvar;
doc_model
  .findOne({aadhar})
  .then(()=>{
    dbvar=1;
  });
paramedic_model
  .findOne({aadhar})
  .then(()=>{
    dbvar=2;
  });
console.log(dbvar);
```

There's 2 collection in my MongoDB and I want to change the variable `dbvar` accordingly. But when it reaches to `console.log(dbvar)`, it shows me **undefined**.

Comment: Try not to declare your dbvar multiple times, declare it once globally and then use.

Comment: @WasifAle Still it's not working after what you mentioned!

Comment: Because you are using asynchronous calls that's why you're not getting the desired output. try to console after calls completion.

Comment: may this is not the right approach, but you can do this by promise chaining `var dbvar = [];
doc_model
  .findOne({
    aadhar
  })
  .then(() => {
    dbvar.push(1);
    return;
  })
  .then(() => {

    paramedic_model
      .findOne({
        aadhar
      })
      .then(() => {
        dbvar.push(2);
        return;
      });
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log(dbvar);
  })`

Answer (score 1):

You are [shadowing your variable](http://eloquentjavascript.net/1st_edition/chapter3.html) `dbvar`, try to remove the variable `dbvar` declaration within your `.then()' functions.

The `console.log` should also be placed within `.then()' so you can see your variable being populated when connection is made (which I suppose in your case is async).

```
var dbvar;
  doc_model
    .findOne({aadhar})
    .then(()=>{
       dbvar=1;
       console.log(dbvar);
    });
  paramedic_model
    .findOne({aadhar})
    .then(()=>{
      dbvar=2;
      console.log(dbvar);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. In JavaScript, declarations in functions do not leak outside.

Your problem is *name shadowing*: By declaring `dbvar` again inside your function, you **shadow** your `dbvar` outside. After declaring `dbvar`in your function, all accesses to that name **dbvar** go to that inner variable.

I think just deleting like this:

```
var dbvar;
...
.then(() => {
   //var dbvar; <-- delete this line
   dbvar=1; // <- can access outer dbvar
   console.log(dbvar); //Log HERE
...
```

Should work

On a different note: You have to access your result from inside your then-callback. You should look up the promises concept a bit more before continuing :)

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Comment: As per you mentioned I did something like this, still not working...
var dbvar;
  doc_model
    .findOne({aadhar})
    .then(()=>{
      dbvar=1;
    });
  paramedic_model
    .findOne({aadhar})
    .then(()=>{
      dbvar=2;
    });
  console.log(dbvar);

Comment: Ok, I will see in that first. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I edited again - the logging has to take place inside of the then-callback. I urge you to look into the asynchronous behaviour of these promises to avoid these issues in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see that `dbvar` is changing it's value.

**Console inside your calls:**

```
var dbvar;
doc_model
  .findOne({aadhar})
  .then(()=>{
     dbvar=1;
     console.log(dbvar);
  });
paramedic_model
  .findOne({aadhar})
  .then(()=>{
    dbvar=2;
    console.log(dbvar);
  });
```

Comment: `setTimeout` is a terrible idea, please do not do that!

Comment: It is just to check in console, otherwise he has to make a waterfall async call to console after completion of all calls.

Comment: It does not matter, do not use `setTimeout` with Promises. Your first example is how you should do it.

Comment: Sure, Thanks ...

Comment: just add console.log inside .then

Answer (score 0):

You are doing some async calls. So js works like this, the call from your `.findOne().then()` might take some time(can take seconds) to complete but during this time JS will keep going through your code so it will get to the `console.log(dbvar);` which is the last line of your code. At this point the `dbvar` will be undefined because you declared it globally like this `var dbvar` with no value. After some time your `.findOne()` will complete so the dbvar will get a value of 1 and 2 but you already printed this before when it was undefined.

There is no problem with your code, you only need to put the console log inside your `.then()` calls

```
var dbvar;
doc_model
  .findOne({aadhar})
  .then(()=>{
    dbvar=1;
    console.log(dbvar);
});
paramedic_model
  .findOne({aadhar})
  .then(()=>{
    dbvar=2;
    console.log(dbvar);
});
```